# Get SOAP XML or header in Axis web service (IBM WebSphere 7)

Tags: java, xml, web-services, soap

I have in my hands, an Axis web service that supposedly receives SOAP requests and gives SOAP responses. This was done by some other people and I don't have any prior experience with **Apache Axis**.

When a test program sends a sample SOAP request to the web service, at first `org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doPost` received the request as an HTTP POST request. It then goes through some processing in Axis2 API which finally calls our own code through reflection.

At this entry point of our code, we can only get what is defined with the `axis` namespace in the SOAP XML request. **What I need is to get the request header or the entire SOAP XML request, through Java.**

A skeleton sample structure is:

```
<Envelope xmlns:axis="soap-service-url">
    <Header>
        some-header-content
    </Header>
    <Body>
        <axis:request>
            <axis:input0>sometext</axis:input0>
            <axis:input1>othertext</axis:input1>
        </axis:request>
    </Body>
</Envelope>
```

At the entry point of our code, we are only getting `sometext` and `othertext` as `String`s. My goal is to get the header, that is `some-header-content`, but I'll be happy if I can just get the entire SOAP XML.

I had been trying to find a solution for quite some time (searched a lot, looked up similar questions in SO), but the more I read up the more I get confused. I have tried:

- Invoke `org.apache.axis.client.Call` object created from `org.apache.axis.client.Service.createCall()` - this always results in a `NullPointerException` no matter what configuration I try for `setTargetEndpointAddress`, `setOperationName`, `setSOAPActionURI` etc.
- `MessageContext.getCurrentContext()` - returns null
- Thought about adding a `Handler` but I'm not sure how to do it, or even how the `Handler` will pass the header content to where I actually need it (aren't handlers asynchronous?)

It is possible my understanding of how Axis functions is wrong and I need to approach this problem differently.